# Different between read(2) and read(1)?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, system-calls

I am newbie for about system calls. In sample code always used `int x=read(...)`
But man page shows different read functions. What is the difference between them? And how to use read(1) instead of read(2)?

Comment: There is only one `read` in C, the other is the shell command `read`.

Comment: [`read`(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/read) is most likely referring to the **bash builtins** command,  the other [`read`(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/read) is the C function.